# Metropolis and Byzanium and node syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, metropolis

Greetings dear ethereum warriors, today I ran into something like that:

```
    WARN [10-09|16:19:01] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=bf7660fbd24a1f07 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
ERROR[10-09|16:19:19] 
########## BAD BLOCK #########
Chain config: {ChainID: 4 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: <nil> Engine: clique}

Number: 1035301
Hash: 0x9e673f84fa096626d50440cbb7c71ec891fd42993be3d99f87c826b43842c592
    receipt{med=a95f1fbd2fa6589acd708d187dfefab5944c64f5eb8eec1c32eb73a8d36a8b88 cgas=27183 bloom=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 logs=[]}


Error: invalid receipt root hash (remote: 85f374e1457eb09d56bf61c66cc7222a7e88167919d5574d3ca132499d06242b local: af3e081c339f29de5d63806d0f04bd152e65c725eb0f2746be748ee041b3e80b)
```

Do you know guys how to fix that? I use rinkeby with basic command from their website:

```
geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --cache=512 --ethstats='yournode:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303
```

Cheers!

Comment: There was a post about it in reddit today https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/758ouw/rinkeby_guide_to_nodes_left_behind_on_how_to/